# Convert HTML with <br>(but without closing br tag) tag to PDF in java

Tags: java, html, pdf-generation

am having few html files, in which few of them are having `<br>` tag but not the closing `br` tag. I am not allowed to modify the HTML files. I want to convert these HTML files to PDF. I tried itext and flying saucer. But am getting same error for the br tag.

```
ERROR:  'The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>".'
```

Is there any way to convert the html to pdf without modifying the html?

Comment: Can try YAHP converter. Sample code : https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-convert-html-to-pdf-using-yahp.html